# count of visible Plots

Tags: mapael

Hi have very simple requirement.

1. I successfully hide all the plots but after that i want to show one particular plot - i know the id of that plot too ( i know we can do by cssClass but it will enable all in that class which i dont want)

   ```
       $(".mapcontainer").trigger('update', [{
               setLegendElemsState: 'hide',
               animDuration: 1000
           }]);
   ```

   // what to do to perform plot['paris'] = ElemsState: show ?????
2. second is the count of visible plots ( specially when u disable some from legend) and show them as text somewhere on
   or

i could try to loop all element and check their current state and show their count.
but i didn't find a way to loop all plot and get their state. new to javascripting

3. is there any possibility to group areas ( countries) to hover as group to reflect the world regions like North America , Europe , Middle east , Asia Pacific.